# How to pass variabel $resultGroup to getColumns Yajra Data Tables?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable, jquery-data

This is the variable that i wanna pass to getColumns function yajra data tables $resultGroup variable

[image]

I want to datatables to this getColumns Yajra Datatables

[image]

How i can parsing $resultGroup to getColumns functions in Yajra Datatables ? And the i wanna ask that getColumns function just can parsing string or can parsing another type data ?

This is the result that i want, and i want to show it to Yajra Datatables.

[image]

I dont know how to parsing this variable $resultGroup to yajra datatables ?

Comment: I think you should put your code in code sample rather than capture the screenshot, it will more easier to investigate the issue..

Comment: Please post code not screenshots

Comment: i've done with it. Thanks guys. I just add the function to addColumn and the i parsing a varible itu the function, and then i declare it on getColumns